# SPIM MIPS simulator assign number to a symbol for reuse later

Tags: assembly

In MIPS, I can allocate space like so:

```
.data
space_here: .space 40 # Allocate 40 bytes
```

Later on, using a SPIM syscall I can read a maximum string of length 40 bytes into this memory location, like so:

```
li $v0, 8 # Syscall number for read string
la $a0, space_here # Load the address of space_here into a0 register
li $a1, 40 # This is the maximum chars to load
syscall
```

However, in the future, I might want to change this and instead have an 80 byte space and load 80 bytes. This means I have to change both occurrences of 40 to 80 in the code.

What I would ideally like to do, is through some kind of preprocessing assign 40 to a symbol, say, 'SPACE_SIZE' then just use this symbol whenever i need to reference the size of the space being allocated.

Is this possible? I tried googling, but finding resources is quite tricky.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the .eqv directive.  It is similar to #define in C or C++.

```
.eqv SPACE_SIZE 40
```

See: http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/MacrosHelp.html

But please, see if you can use a better name then, `SPACE_SIZE`.

Re google: found this with a ["SPIM MIPS simulator preprocessor"](https://www.google.com/search?q=SPIM+MIPS+simulator&oq=SPIM+MIPS+simulator&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=SPIM+MIPS+simulator+preprocessor) search.

Comment: Note to future people:

This is for the mars MIPS sim, not the 'spim' sim you can find using apt-get install. Further research reveals a spim preprocessor which can be run using the 'app' command (assembly pre-processor) but in the end I personally just switched to mars. 

The 'built in' kernel your program runs on top of contains more syscalls, and it even comes with an IDE (though you can still run from command line with java -jar Mars.jar program.s).